# Halachic ramifications of using a digital lollipop

Tags: fast-days, mon-manna, taste

A device known as the digital lollipop sends electric signals to the tongue, stimulating taste. It can theoretically represent any taste, when correctly coupled with a smelling device, similar to how the Mon could taste like anything.

Here's a video demonstration:
[Digital Lollipop Stimulation](https://youtube.com/watch?v=sSJ63KXyMqU)

May one stimulate their tongue with an electronic device that simulates taste and use it on a fast day, or attempt to "taste" the flavor of non-kosher food?

Comment: I think this question would be more compelling if you clarified if one is allowed to *actually* taste things (without consumption) on a fast, or taste non kosher. If not, then your question starts

Comment: Yom Kippur (inuy) vs other fasts?

Comment: Why not stimulate the brain straight?

Comment: Taste is limited to a couple of distinctive sensors and the rest is formed memories of different combinations of those (just as sight). A pious Jew would not have a memory of a taste of non-kosher food, therefore tasting one will necessarily taste as something he remembers. Imagine, I've given a taste of a starfish I never touched. Will I recognize it? Surely not.

Comment: Hanas goron is the main issue on a fast day

Answer (score 1):

Regarding tasting food on fast day the Shulchan Aruch
567:1 allows a taste up to a reviis if nothing is swallowed ,the Rama is stringent. Regarding non kosher taste, the gemara in chullin 109b writes about the Shibuta fish which is kosher and tasted like pork,which is permissible, so too this digital case.